# MatchCase:=False).row and "run-time error 91"

Tags: vba, excel, commandbutton

I want to enter in some text and values in a `commandbutton` and have it populate a spreadsheet.  my code is here:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("table1").Range


LastRow = rng.Find(What:=” * ”, _
    After:=rng.Cells(1), _
    Lookat:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Row

    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = ComboBox1.Text
    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).Value = TextBox3.Value
    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 4).Value = TextBox4.Value
    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 5).Value = TextBox5.Value

End Sub
```

I keep getting run-time error 91 on `matchcase:=false).row` and I don't know why.  An extra set of eyes would be so helpful.

Comment: Since you have a `ListObject`, you can use [`ListRows.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listrows-add-method-excel) to add a row at the end.

Comment: forgive me, but I am not following you.  would it be possible to get more explanation?  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're adding a row to an existing table (`ListObject`). There's no need to find the last row - you can just use [`ListRows.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listrows-add-method-excel). If you don't specify the position you want the row to be added at, it is automatically added at the bottom.

This simplifies what you are trying to do.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim newRow As ListRow
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("table1")
    Set newRow = tbl.ListRows.Add

    With newRow
        .Range(1) = Textbox1.Text
        .Range(2) = ComboBox1.Text
        .Range(3) = TextBox3.Value
        .Range(4) = TextBox4.Value
        .Range(5) = TextBox5.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: oh shoot...you are correct.  I was definitely over complicating it.  much appreciated BigBen.  :)